# Access Denied error when attempting to save Excel spreadsheet files with Microsoft Office

Tags: windows, ubuntu, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, samba

I have a server running Samba Version 3.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. Some users are receiving the following error message when trying to save changes to an Excel spreadsheet file (mounted from a Samba network share) using Microsoft Office on Windows:

```
Access Denied. Contact your Administrator.
```

Apparently they are able to open the file without any issues. Also, I am able to modify the file using LibreOffice.

Here is the smb.conf entry for the associated network share:

```
[groupX]
    comment = shared files for groupX
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    path = /export/groups/groupX
    guest ok = no
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 2775
    inherit owner = yes
    inherit permissions = yes
    directory mask = 2775
    force directory mode = 2775
    directory security mask = 2775
    force directory security mode = 2775
    force group = +groupX
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its probably that the file is open for edit by another user at that time. have you been able to confirm that there are no other open handles to it, by running `lsof` or simmilar on the server when you get the trouble report?

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for the comment. I'm actually fairly certain that this isn't the case, because I received a different (more detailed) error message when the file was open. It also doesn't seem clear to me why I am consistently able to edit the file and save changes (in LibreOffice on Linux) while the Windows users are consistently unable to save changes to the file.

Comment: are the affected users affected 100% of the time, or is it a sometimes kinda thing?

Comment: @FrankThomas According to them it's 100% of the time.

Comment: and they are all members of groupx? have you confirmed that the actual file system permissions for all the objects have the owner-group groupx, and that the permissions you specify have been propagated to all objects in the share? Samba permissions stack atop file system permissions, so they need to be the same (or arranged to compliment eachother), and samba won't change the permissions on anything that wasn't created THROUGH samba, so its worth a double check.